# Get size of char buffer for sprintf handling longs C

Tags: c, pointers, long-integer

I am quite new to C and occurred a question, when dealing with long ints/char* in C. I want to store a long in a char*, but I am not sure, how I should manage the size of my buffer to fit any long given.
Thats what I want:

```
char buffer[LONG_SIZE]; // what should LONG_SIZE be to fit any long, not depending on the OS?
sprintf(buffer, "%ld", some_long);
```

I need to use C not C++. Is there any solution to this, if I don't want to use magic-numbers?

Comment: Number of digits = number of bits / 3.32 + 1 for sign +1 for null terminator. So 32 bits needs 12, 64 needs 22, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> if I don't want to use magic-numbers

Using [`snprintf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) with a 0-length buffer will return the number of chars needed to hold the result (Minus the trailing 0). You can then allocate enough space to hold the string on demand:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(void) {
  long some_long = LONG_MAX - 5;
  // Real code should include error checking and handling.
  int len = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%ld", some_long);
  char *buffer = malloc(len + 1);
  snprintf(buffer, len + 1, "%ld", some_long);
  printf("%s takes %d chars\n", buffer, len);
  free(buffer);
}
```

There's also [`asprintf()`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html), available in Linux glibc and some BSDs, that allocates the result string for you, with a more convenient (But less portable) interface than the above.

Allocating the needed space on demand instead of using a fixed size has some benefits; it'll continue to work without further adjustment if you change the format string at some point in the future, for example.

Even if you stick with a fixed length buffer, I recommend using `snprintf()` over `sprintf()` to ensure you won't somehow overwrite the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably more correct to use `snprintf` to compute the necessary size, but it seems like this should work:

```
char buf[ sizeof(long) * CHAR_BIT ];
```

Answer (score 1):

The number of bits in a `long` is `sizeof long * CHAR_BIT`. (`CHAR_BIT` is defined in `<limits.h>`.) This can represent at most a signed number of magnitude 2<sup>`sizeof long * CHAR_BIT - 1`</sup>.

Such a number can have at most floor(log<sub>10</sub>2<sup>`sizeof long * CHAR_BIT - 1`</sup>)+1 decimal digits. This is floor(`(sizeof long * CHAR_BIT - 1)` * log<sub>10</sub>2) + 1. log<sub>10</sub>2 is less than .302, so `(sizeof long * CHAR_BIT - 1)` * 302 / 1000 + 1 bytes is enough for the digits.

Add one for a sign and one for a terminating null character, and `char[(sizeof long * CHAR_BIT - 1) * 302 / 1000 + 3]` suffices for the buffer.